# PyMuPDF: It is possible to get a face value from a combobox widget?

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

I am trying to extract a chosen value from a combobox widget using the following Python code:

```
#Extract data from combobox
import fitz
fileIN_Master = "Mypdf.pdf"     
with fitz.open(fileIN_Master) as doc:
for page in doc: 
widgets = page.widgets()
for widget in widgets:
if widget.field_type_string in ('ComboBox'):
print('field_name:', widget.field_name, 'field_value:', widget.field_value)
```

All I can get is field name and export value (field_name). I was wondering if it is possible to get the face value as well.

Comment: Answered in PyMuPD's website "Discussion" tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combo box item may have 1 or 2 sub items. If you have the Widget object `w` you can do this to access both values where present:

```py
In [5]: w.field_value
Out[5]: 'England'
In [6]: [item for item in w.choice_values if w.field_value in item]
Out[6]: [('England', 'GB')]
In [8]: w.choice_values  # all available values: there are items with 1 or 2 subitems
Out[8]:
[('Spanien', 'ES'),
 ('Frankreich', 'F'),
 ('Holland', 'NL'),
 ('Dänemark', 'DK'),
 ('Schweden', 'S'),
 ('Norwegen', 'N'),
 ('England', 'GB'),
 ('Polen', 'P'),
 'Italien',
 'Portugal',
 'Griechenland']
```